# I am unable to build the project using apache-maven3.2.2

Tags: java, apache, maven, wagon

I am unable to build the project using Apache-maven 3.2.2 and As i am new to the maven i am not able to find the issue. Please provide some solutions to resolve it.

And the error as follows:

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin 
  org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ftp:1.0-beta-2 or one of its dependencies could 
  not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
  org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ftp:jar:1.0-beta-2: Could not transfer artifact
  org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ftp:pom:1.0-beta-2 from/to central 
  (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host 
  repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 2]
```

and my maven version as follows:

```
C:\Users\xyz>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.2 (45f7c06d68e745d05611f7fd14efb6594181933e; 2014-06-17T19:21:42+05:30)
Maven home: D:\software\Maven\apache-maven-3.2.2-bin\apache-maven-3.2.2
Java version: 1.7.0_01, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows nt (unknown)", version: "6.2", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem accessing the Internet. Is there a proxy involved? `http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` definitely exist.

Comment: Apart from that why are you using such an ancient wagon-ftp version...Current version is 2.10 ;-)

Comment: Same for me, remark that wagon is declared as an <extension>, not as a <depedency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your maven path , you have to give bin as your maven path

Answer (score 0):

In your pom.xml, try to find this dependency.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
<artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-beta-2</version>
</dependency>
```

and you can change it with the following artifact;

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
<artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
<version>2.10</version>
</dependency>
```

if it does not work, the problem is with your internet settings, as Tunaki said.